# VBA macro, unable to access file on OneDriveFB when not in the office

Tags: vba, excel, onedrive

My VBA macro has this line of code:

```
Workbooks.Open FileName:="https://<MyOneDriveForBusinessFolder>/<MyFileName.xlsm>"
```

The whole macro works fine for users in the company office, but fails on the above line for users logging to corporate network from remote locations.
The folder is shared with entire security group, all users have "Can View" access level.
All users, including those for whom the code fails, are able to access the folder/file via browser.
Not sure if this is of any importance, but as this is OneDrive for Business, I believe the file is encrypted.

Can anyone advise please, why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your corporate OneDrive instance is location restricted. There's nothing Excel can do to overcome that. It's a security feature.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Difster. If it's the location restriction, then why can the file be accessed manually by user, but not through automation? All my users' laptops are the same domain-joined machines with the same image on them, and the remote users are always within the same small city. All user corporate accounts are on the same domain. Lastly, since yesterday, three users in the office reported the same problem, so now I am completely baffled by this :(

Comment: In that case, I don't have an answer. You should see if you can get any logging from OneDrive to see if you can discern something from them.

Comment: So after some unpredictable behavior yesterday, I gave everyone "Can Edit" rights to the folder and the problem went away. This is a sub-optimal solution, but I can live with it until I find the cause or a better solution. Thanks again, Difster for your help!